# Data structure libraries in memcached

Tags: java, data-structures, memcached

It's possible to write queues, stacks, vectors, linked list, sets, etc. all in memcached.  I'm wondering if there are any libraries that have implemented any of these data structures?  We'll be in Java probably and will otherwise have a need to write some of these by ourselves.

"Thread-safety" is important, in that two processes living on different machines should be able to use the same library to manipulate these structures concurrently.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that I have not misunderstood your question - which is quite possible :)

You can look at HazelCast (Java API - distributed maps, mutitmaps, sets, lists queues, topics), Redis (Jedis Java API - Sets, maps, lists, topics etc.).  Hazelcast replication is quite simple (you have to specify whether you're going to use tcp based or multicast replication) - with redis, you could look into using messaging for replication (I do not think cluster is available in a stable  release but you should do your own due diligence).

Answer (score 0):

You may use [Redisson](https://github.com/mrniko/redisson). It implements distributed and scalable Java data structures (Set, Map, ConcurrentMap, List, Queue, Lock, AtomicLong, CountDownLatch, Publish / Subscribe) on top of Redis.